# How to generate Azure O365 APIs to get user details which we have created on azure portal using php

Tags: php, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am new to `AZURE O365` portal, I have created some users in azure portal.
How can I create API in Azure portal to get the user details which I have already created in the portal and are they users enabled or disabled using `PHP`.

I tried: I have created application and I created secret Id in the portal, then what I have to do, to generate API for user list using php.

please help on it.

Thanks
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I undestand you correctly: you created some users on the azure portal and you want to get these users using PHP?

Azure has many APIs, they also have an API for getting these users, here is the specification and example code (not in php, but I think still easy to understand):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Basically you can access that data using graphql client. There are many graphql libraries for php. But as I skimmed through the docs, you don't really need a library, just a way to create http requests, I recommend Guzzle.
Before you create that php code, I recommend to simply play with the API by using postman or other api client. If it works there, you can start to create the php code.

The code is basically a http POST request (or whatever is specified in the documentation). The request should contain your API tokens in the header, thats all. Data will be provided usually as JSON. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494526/can-i-use-guzzle-for-graphql-api-consumption) are some examples how to use guzzle in php for graph.

Comment: The Graph API is not a GraphQL API so you don't need a GraphQL library. There's an official MS Graph library for PHP that you can use: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php